# An error while using a local SMTP pickup directory

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I am configuring SMTPClient with these codes to use local directory:

EmailHelper.cs

```
  public bool SendMail(string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml)
        {
            try
            {
                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                string pickUpFolder = @"C:\Users\kerem\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Blog\Blog\Email";
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                Configuration configurationFile = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
                MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
                if (mailSettings != null)
                {
                    pickUpFolder = mailSettings.Smtp.SpecifiedPickupDirectory.PickupDirectoryLocation;
                    smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = pickUpFolder;
                }


                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                if (cc != "")
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = body;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

EmailHelper.cs in BlogServices Project in my Blog solution. Also there is a Blog Project in the same solution. I have replaced `Blog\Blog\Email` in `pickUpFolder` with `Blog\Email` and `Blog\BlogServices\Email` but I still have an error of *Only absolute directories are allowed for pickup directory.*  Where  is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the `system.net/mailSettings` section of your web.config?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your project's web.config.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\kerem\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Blog\Blog\Email\"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Alternatively, try deleting this line: `pickUpFolder = mailSettings.Smtp.SpecifiedPickupDirectory.PickupDirectoryLocation;`, but I suspect you'll have other problems if you go that route.

Comment: That is a saver. it solved my problem. Also do not misplace the "s" with "S" in "mailSettings" or else it won't work.

Comment: Nice one this solves the need for a real smtp server setup for dev environment or test environments